# Logout from web console?

Tags: web, console

I'm really new to eJabber, and I don't seem to be able to find a better way to log-out from the web admin console other the closing and opening the browser.
Is there any button to log-out?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Well, I may have been a bit too vague about what I'm trying to accomplish. I apologize. I'm trying to set up a stand alone ejabberd server on my localhost (using latest macOS). So I've downloaded and installed it in my /Applications folder.
Now after fiddling a bit with various configurations, I wanted to try to log in and out from the web admin interface. Actually I'm trying to enter the web admin interface with different user names.
Therefore the point is, just to answer HBruijn's answer, "what is the point of having a login at all, then"?
When I browse to http://localhost:5280/admin, I'm presented a LOGIN window, with username/password fields and nice "LOGIN" button.
And even after login , there's no cookie or session variable stored in the browser.
So, how do I say to my browser (and eJabber) that I'm not the user adminAAA@my-local-domain.local but adminBBB@my-local-domain.local?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know that particular product but anything that uses http [basic authentication](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) does NOT come with a log off button.

Since with basic auth there  is no session maintained server side no server side  function  can terminate the login session.

And AFAIK no browser  ever implemented doing so client side.

Comment: Please see my edited post